# Ruby default class actions after require

Tags: ruby, goliath

I remember that this problem came up before but I can't find the answer.

I require a file this way:

```
#lib/tm/agent/server.rb
require 'tm/agent/server'
```

And, without calling the Listen class explicitly, its `initialize` gets executed:

```
module Tm
  module Agent
    module Server

      require 'goliath'

      class Listen < Goliath::API
        def initialize
          puts "WHAT"
        end
        def response(env)
          [200, {}, "Hello World"]
        end
      end

    end #end Server
  end #end Agent
end #end Tm
```

How do I avoid initializing the class on require?

Comment: Maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745252/require-file-without-executing-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a hook in the Goliath server that automatically starts a server when you run your script directly – it’s not a normal feature of Ruby.

To avoid it, don’t call `require 'goliath'`, but use `require 'goliath/api'` instead.

Comment: I guess I just need to pay attention that some libraries behave this way.